# Identify white element on back of Apple monitor

Tags: part-identification

Please help me identify this part - the white piece / pieces at the back? [image]The instructions are no longer available and all i can find is this fuzzy picture. I can work out the rest, but this has baffled me. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like this may be [Chris McVeigh's iMac](https://www.cultofmac.com/95396/build-your-own-lego-imac-for-100/) design? Looks like [the wayback machine may have some LXF files archived](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://web.me.com/chrismcveigh/mintinbox/home/Entries/2011/2/23_Lego_iMac_files/*) if that is useful to you.

Answer (score 7):

If I understand which part you are referring to, it looks like [Hinge Plate 3 x 4 Locking Dual 2 Finger (44570)](https://rebrickable.com/parts/44302a/hinge-plate-1-x-2-locking-with-2-fingers-on-end-with-groove/15/) to me.

[image: part render]

It's tough to tell for sure what it is connected to, but it is probably [Hinge Plate 1 x 4 Locking Dual 1 Finger (44568)](https://rebrickable.com/parts/44568/hinge-plate-1-x-4-locking-dual-1-finger/)

[image: part render]

Comment: Thank you, it is Chris' but can't find the build guide anywhere! It's been taken off. I had a feeling it was that hinge plate, will try that, thanks so much!